# focal - prevent networkd from performing a dhcprelease

Tags: dhcp, systemd-networkd

We have an issue with focal/networkd and our dhcp-server which gives some (not all) hosts a new ipaddress when they reboot.
The network guys says it is due to the dhclient sends a DHCPRELEASE so I would like to force networkd to stop sending the DHCPRELEASE packet.

I tried creating a /etc/systemd/network/default.network file with:

```
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
KeepConfiguration=dhcp

[DHCPv4]
SendRelease=false
```

Which according to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/systemd.network.5.html look correct but it doesnt work, hosts are still getting new ipaddresses and I still get "DHCP lease lost" in the logs when hosts are rebooted:

```
-- Reboot --
apr 05 10:47:47 lab01-wrk4 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
apr 05 10:47:47 lab01-wrk4 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Succeeded.
apr 05 10:47:47 lab01-wrk4 systemd-networkd[744]: ens192: DHCP lease lost
apr 05 10:47:47 lab01-wrk4 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
```

Last note: the hosts are VMs created from the same template but Ive tried the usual stuff like making sure /etc/machine-id is unique and also tried with ClientIdentifier=mac in networkd ...

Any suggestions?

Thanks ...

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu is being used?

Comment: Hi, 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Comment: Maybe "the network guys" could give you some static leases to use with VM's?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP lease times are usually set at the router. Even if sendRelease is false, the router will usually revoke DHCP lease after it expires. If you're trying to do this on your private network, make sure you login to your router and use address reservation to keep the same IP for your device's MAC address.

Comment: Hi, these are VMs automatically created by terraform using a vSphere-template so the VMs macaddress is not known beforehand. Plus we dont have permission to automate IPAM at the moment.
So any address reservation is not possible (at the moment)

Comment: So to clarify, the lease isnt expired when the host reboots and the gets a new ipaddress from the dhcp. It could be a config issue with the dhcp server or it could be something how ubuntu does things which the dhcp server doesnt handle well.

So primarily I would just like to be able to not do the DHCP_RELEASE and see if that helps ...